# What does the 'h' stand for in the hexadecimal value '4D42h', and why are the bytes reversed?

Tags: ascii, endianness, bitmapimage, hex

I'm currently reading about BMP file formats and [I've come across the following lines of code](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm) which are used to define a bitmap file header.

```
typedef struct _WinBMPFileHeader
{
    WORD   FileType;     /* File type, always 4D42h ("BM") */
    DWORD  FileSize;     /* Size of the file in bytes */
    WORD   Reserved1;    /* Always 0 */
    WORD   Reserved2;    /* Always 0 */
    DWORD  BitmapOffset; /* Starting position of image data in bytes */
} WINBMPFILEHEADER;
```

The first comment claims that `4D42h` is identical to `BM`.

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart) `4D` is the hexadecimal ASCII code for `M`, while `42` is the ASCII code for `B`.

What does the `h` stand for, though?

And why isn't `4D42h` identical to `MB` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context `h` stands for hexadecimal notation.

For the order, you need to consider the endianess of your processor, where in this case they are stored on disk in a different byte order, than logically in memory.

Comment: Thanks. I was familiar with the `0x##` convention for denoting hexadecimal values but I've never come across `##h`.